# KML Show direction of movement on line

Tags: kml, google-earth

In a Google Earth KML that I generate I'm trying to indicate the direction of movement along a LinePath with an arrow. As such, for each data point on the line I made a palace mark, in which I specified an arrow icon in my style, and added a heading element to it. So my style section for each place mark looks like this:

```
<Style>
    <IconStyle>
        <Icon>
            <href>...<href>
        </Icon>
        <heading>[appropriate heading for point]</heading>
    </IconStyle>
</Style>
```

And this works great when viewing the path from a top-down perspective:

[image: top-down view]

As you can see, the arrows point along the path in the direction of movement, as desired. However, if I try to view the path from a more oblique angle, i.e. looking along the path or across the path rather than down at the path, things change:

[image: oblique view]

Now instead of pointing along the path, the arrows are pointing angled downwards. To be correct, the icons would need to be rotated several degrees counter-clockwise. This is using the same KML in both views, only the viewing angle in Google Earth has changed. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you view the icons looking straight down the heading will be correct but once look at scene in 3-D with a tilt then the icons will tilt accordingly.

To have an arrow in direction of the heading then best approach using KML is to represent your point data in [Track](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxtrack) element assuming you have a timestamp with each point. The heading, speed, etc. is calculated from each waypoint and arrow direction always points in the direction based on the current time in the time slider.

Tracks can also be viewed with elevation profile showing both elevation and speed.
[image: Track example with elevation profile]

You can find a Track example [here](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2010/07/making-tracks-new-kml-extensions-in.html).